# C#: Analysis Tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I would like to know if there are any tool for Visual Studio 2010 to detect deadlocks and bootlenecks. I am trying PostSharp right now. Some others? I prefer freeware but I do not discard commercial ones. Ideas?

Comment: http://chesstool.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Performance Wizard from Visual Studio. For sure this tool is added to the Ultimate version. Using this tool you can see for example how many % of time your application is spending on what method. It has a really nice and clear layout. For me sometimes it was very useful. If you have in "up" menu in VS "Analyze" tab you can find it there.

Comment: I do not have Visual Studio ultimate edition. I have the professional version and I do not see Performance wizard.... Where is it?

Comment: Unfortunately in professional edition you haven't this tool http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products